# How to force Heroku PHP app to use SSL certificate (https)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, heroku, mod-rewrite

I am trying to force my heroku web app to use the automatic certificate offered from heroku. I need to force all my links to use https. So I added lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

To the htaccess file, but now I get the error "This page isn't working, too many redirects". What do I put in my htaccess file to force https? Everyone online I've found uses this, but if I delete my other rules my website does not load.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. In Laravel under AppServiceProvider.php, you can put this is the boot() function to force https on your laravel app.

Hope this helps anyone!

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    if($this->app->environment('production')) {
        \URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Everyone online I've found uses this

Is that "everyone" using Heroku?

I believe Heroku uses a *reverse proxy* to manage the SSL certificate, so you can't use the Apache `HTTPS` server variable, since your application is actually communicating over plain HTTP to the proxy.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The reverse proxy sets the `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP request header, informing the application of the type of request that the client made to the proxy.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not also putting `QSA` into your flag list, à la `[QSA, L, R=301]` (`QSA` appends query string) ?

Comment: @foobored The `QSA` flag is not required here. The query string from the original request is appended by default when you don't explicitly include a query string in the _substitution_ string. You only need the `QSA` flag if you want to _merge_ the original query string with a new query string you have specified in the _substitution_. eg. `RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?new=foo [QSA,L,R=301]`